aad-auth and KDE: Login works but unlock does not
I have an Ubuntu 24.04 (upgraded from 23), with aad-auth installed and configured. It has been working properly with Gnome, both before and after the upgrade, I've been using an MS account for almost 1 year.
With KDE however everything works except unlocking the session.
Looking at the logs, it seems to be a permissions issue:
Oct 10 12:56:39 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): aad auth debug enabled
Oct 10 12:56:39 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): PAM AAD DEBUG enabled
Oct 10 12:56:39 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): Loading configuration from /etc/aad.conf
Oct 10 12:56:39 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): Connecting to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>", with clientID "<CLIENT_ID>" for user "user@domain.com"
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): Authentication successful even if requiring MFA
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): Cache initialization
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): Opening cache in /var/lib/aad/cache
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): check file permissions on /var/lib/aad/cache/passwd.db
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): check file permissions on /var/lib/aad/cache/shadow.db
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): Shadow db mode: 0
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): getting user information from cache for "user@domain.com"
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): encrypt password for user "user@domain.com"
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): updating from last online login information for user "user@domain.com"
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): couldn't create/open cache for nss database: failed to update user "user@domain.com" in local cache: shadow database is not accessible for writing: 0. Denying access.
Oct 10 12:56:41 host1 kscreenlocker_greet[8957]: pam_aad(kde:auth): Close database request

The files under /var/lib/aad/cache are owned by root, the sddm login runs as root, kscreenlocker_greet runs as the logged in user.
I can't figure out how to fix this the right way. If I try running the greeter as root (leaving aside the security implications), it stops working completely.
